# What's the meaning of "throw out"

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

> Ultimate fist pumping workout.
>
> My friend threw out her shoulder by fist pumping at a club once.

The comment was made from a gif. In this gif, it shows a man doing a workout holding a barbell without the plates while pumping his fists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means they dislocated their shoulder joint.

Comment: I've no doubt that's what's meant, but my preferred (British English) version would be *"My friend **put her shoulder out** by..."*